# How to create blanks for certain entries in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(17.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 B = c(22.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
                 C = c(2.4, 5.5, 1.8, 3.3))

     A    B   C
1 17.1 22.2 2.4
2  0.0  0.0 5.5
3  0.0  0.0 1.8
4  0.0  0.0 3.3
```

For viewing with View() I want to have blank entries for rows 2-4 where I have 0.0 elements. Here is the desired output:

```
     A    B   C
1 17.1 22.2 2.4
2           5.5
3           1.8
4           3.3
```

One way to do this would be to turn df columns into characters, and set the “0.0” characters to “ “. Ideally, I’d like to have the non-zero elements remain numerics if possible. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `df[df==0.0] <- ""`

Comment: if you want the column to remain numeric you will have to replace the 0.0 with `NA`, `df[df==0.0] <- NA`

Comment: Mike, I guess there is no really good way to avoid having the NAs show. Yes, I do want to retain the numeric nature of the df, as I use it for other calculations. My solution will be to create a character version of df for View() and keep the numeric version for calculations. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print using the zero.print option in the `format` function to print the data frame.

```
print(format(df, zero.print=""))

     A    B   C
1 17.1 22.2 2.4
2           5.5
3           1.8
4           3.3
```

Another option is using the `kable` function from the `knitr` package.

```
knitr::kable(df, format.args= list(zero.print = ""))


|    A|    B|   C|
|----:|----:|---:|
| 17.1| 22.2| 2.4|
|     |     | 5.5|
|     |     | 1.8|
|     |     | 3.3|
```